# Cannot import "BasicBlock" from torchvision.models.resnet

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, pytorch

I am trying to import the class `BasicBlock` from `torchvision.models.resnet` by doing this

```
from torchvision.models.resnet import *
```

It is giving no error but when I am trying to use `BasicBlock` class in my code (which is supposed to be imported already), I am getting the error that

`NameError: name 'BasicBlock' is not defined`

even though `BasicBlock` is present in `torchvision.models.resnet`

But it gives no error when I import like this

`from torchvision.models.resnet import BasicBlock`

and then use it in my code

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`BasicBlock` is indeed defined, however it is not exported by the module: see [here](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/master/torchvision/models/resnet.py#L8) the definition of `__all__`. So *torchvision/models/resnet.py* only exports these: `ResNet`, `resnet18`, `resnet34`, `resnet50`, `resnet101`, `resnet152`, `resnext50_32x4d`, `resnext101_32x8d`, `wide_resnet50_2`, and `wide_resnet101_2`.

Comment: But even though the functions "conv1x1" and "conv3x3" are not in "__ all __" I don't get an error even if I don't import those separately.

Comment: Are you sure about that? I can't replicate this issue with `conv1x1` and `conv3x3`, they both raise an error as `BasicBlock` does.

Comment: I am saying that I am not getting an error even if I don't import those functions.

Comment: So you did `from torchvision.models.resnet import *` and were able to use `conv1x1` and conv3x3`?

Comment: I did not use those functions directly,  but those functions were used inside BasicBlock and also ResNet

Comment: They are all defined in the same file, that's why they are accessible there.

Comment: Okay!! Understood!! Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 2):

`BasicBlock` is imported under `torchvision.models` however it is not advisable to do `import *`and importing everything but incase you want to do that then use `from torchvision.models import *` you will not get the error.

`import *` imports everything under `__all__` variable and this variable in resnet has `['ResNet', 'resnet18', 'resnet34', 'resnet50', 'resnet101','resnet152', 'resnext50_32x4d', 'resnext101_32x8d','wide_resnet50_2', 'wide_resnet101_2']` that why it is throwing up error `NameError` for `BasicBlock`